# Prolog, working with capital letter

Tags: variables, prolog

I am working on database project in SWI-Prolog. Problem is that i want to work with names of Sportsmen which i read from input. I need to save their names with capital letters, but prolog interprets these as variables. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you look at the SWI documentation, there is quite a bit of support for character and string manipulation and I/O. There is, for example, `to_upper/2` or `to_lower/2` for converting a character to/from upper and lower case. There are also predicates such as `read_line_to_codes/2` which will read a "raw" input line rather than attempting to interpret it as a Prolog term (which is what `read/1` does). You might also want to look at `atom_codes/2`. Have a look at those, give something a try, and see if you have more specific questions afterwards.

Comment: In my answer I use `code_type/2` which has the `lower/1`, `to_lower/1`, `upper/1`, and `to_upper/1` options of the second argument. `char_type/2` works the same way, but on single-character atoms. SWI has quite some support for case-conversion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `code_type/2` to ensure that any entered name starts with a capital letter.

Since you want to allow a user to enter a name with a letter that is either lower- or uppercase, I do the case conversion on the codes list that I read with `read_line_to_codes/2`.

Since you want to store the names in a database, I use `dynamic/1` to declare that I will be adding some `sportsname/1` entries, and I use `assert/1` to add a specific name to the database.

Here is the code:

```
:- dynamic(sportsname/1).

:- initialization(input).

input:-
  repeat,
  format(user_output, 'Please enter a name (or type `quit`):\n', []),
  read_line_to_codes(user_input, Codes1),
  (
    atom_codes(quit, Codes1)
  ->
    !, true
  ;
    capitalize(Codes1, Codes2)
  ->
    atom_codes(Name, Codes2),
    assert(sportsname(Name)),
    format(current_output, 'Sportsname ~a writen to database.\n', [Name]),
    fail
  ;
    fail
  ).

capitalize([], []).
capitalize([H1|T], [H2|T]):-
  code_type(H2, to_upper(H1)).
```

Example of use:

```
$ swipl sport_names.pl
Please enter a name (or type `quit`):
|: john
Sportsname John writen to database.
Please enter a name (or type `quit`):
|: James
Sportsname James writen to database.
Please enter a name (or type `quit`):
|: suzan
Sportsname Suzan writen to database.
Please enter a name (or type `quit`):
|: quit

?- sportsname(X).
X = 'John' ;
X = 'James' ;
X = 'Suzan'.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thx a lot ! I can't say i understand all of the code you posted but it solved my problem anyway.

Comment: @user3568104 `repeat` means that the program returns to that point in the code after a user has added a name. This allows a user to enter multiple names consecutively. Since the program would otherwise never end (it keeps repeating!), I use `!, true` to exit from the loop.

Comment: @user3568104 Than is the conditional statement `( IF -> THEN ; ELSE)`. So it says: "If the user gave input 'quit', then exit the loop; else, if we can make the user's input start with a capital letter, we add it to the database and ask the user for the next input; in all other cases we simply ask the user to enter another input."

Comment: well, mby i am still not getting it, but i had to add this code after assert so that it would really write those names into database.

Code: 
 tell('Sposrtsname.pl'),
 listing(sportsname),
 told,

Also i put those dynamic sportsmen into sepparate file because otherwise all the code was overwriten when writing to database.

Answer (score 1):

Use either quoted atoms...

```
?- atom('X').
true.

?- 'X' = 'Y'.
false.
```

... or strings:

```
?- X = "Foo!".
X = [70, 111, 111, 33].
```

(strings are represented as lists of codepoints, in this case ASCII ones). Quoted atoms are much easier to work with.

Comment: Problem is that i dont want users to write quoted strings. I want them just to write Usain Bolt so i will have Usain Bolt stored in my database.

Comment: @user3568104 Then you'll need to write a custom input parser instead of relying on Prolog syntax.

Comment: Isnt there simply some predicate to turn first letter to upper case??

Comment: @user3568104: no, that would be too easy (seriously, Prolog's string processing is as bad as C's; you'll need [term manipulation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=manipatom) and [character type handling](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chartype) for this). But then you still need to input the string with a lowercase initial letter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how implementation independent this code is, but this works for me in SWI-Prolog:

```
read_string(String) :-
    current_input(Input),
    read_line_to_codes(Input, Codes),
    string_codes(String, Codes).
```

Sample input and output:

```
?- read_string(X).
|: Test!
X = "Test!".
```

Comment: (+1) I like this solution. But I couldn't find `string_codes/2` in my SWI Prolog (6.0.2). I did, however, find `char_codes/2` which does what this needs.

Comment: @lurker, that's strange you couldn't find `string_codes/2` and I can't find `char_codes/2` :-) maybe its the same predicate but with changed name in later versions of SWI Prolog (I have version 6.6.4).

Comment: Oops, I messed up. I meant `atom_codes/2` not `char_codes/2`. That's a pretty significant version difference. Perhaps `string_codes/2` it was added. I assume that SWI 6.6.4 has `atom_codes/2` and `atom_chars/2`. I used `atom_codes` in place of `string_codes` in your solution and get the expected result, `'Test!'` (single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Just quote any string that need to be read by Prolog, regardless to the case you find in the database... Beware to escaping: for instance

```
?- write('O\'Neal').
O'Neal

?- read(X).
|: 'O\'Neal'.
X = 'O\'Neal'.
```