# Basis about input and ouput in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog

Can anyone tell me where can I find a nice documentation about input and output in Prolog? I need to ask some questions to the users based on some facts and rules. For example:

```
best_team(bestteam).
```

And ask in SWI-Prolog: *Can you guest what the best team name is?*

So the user can write like `bestteam` and I Prolog answer for example: *You are right!*

Something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: I have asked myself this question many times, so I made some doc myself, [available at github](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/prolog_output_formatting.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example shown can be done with the basic I/O routines, `write/1`, `read/1`, and `nl/0`:

```
best_team(bills).

main :-
    repeat,
    write('Can you guest what the best team name is?'), nl,
    read(X),
    best_team(X),
    write('You are right!'), nl, !.

| ?- main.
Can you guest what the best team name is?
giants.
Can you guest what the best team name is?
bills.
You are right!

yes
| ?-
```

This can easily be extended to give a "You are wrong!" message for a wrong response. One way would be:

```
main :-
    repeat,
    write('Can you guest what the best team name is?'), nl,
    read(X),
    (   best_team(X)
    ->  write('You are right!'), nl, !
    ;   write('You are wrong!'), nl, fail
    ).
```

This will result in:

```
| ?- main.
Can you guest what the best team name is?
giants.
You are wrong!
Can you guest what the best team name is?
bills.
You are right!

yes
| ?-
```

If you want to enter input with punctuation, capitalized words, etc, then you'll need to use other predicates. There was a [recent question posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264828/prolog-working-with-capital-letter) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Lurker! Can you tell me how can I add the wrong response? Do you have any suggest for learning these things? Link, Book, whatever.

Comment: @Checho I added a little to the answer per your extra questions. The link shows a little more on some I/O ideas in SWI Prolog. I think a good book on foundations of Prolog, including the basic I/O, is *Programming in Prolog* by Clocksin & Mellish (5th Edition). Also, browse the SWI Prolog I/O predicates in their online manual, read what they do, and play with a couple. They have a few examples, but unfortunately no extensive tutorials.