# create rules from sentence prolog

Tags: prolog

I have next sentence:

John is a footballer. Mary is an actress. All of Mary's friends are footballers and are blond (*their hair*). All of John's friends are footballers or actors.

How could I get into prolog **last two** sentences if I did first two.

```
footballer(john).
actor(Mary).
```

Comment: consider actor and actress as same variable - actor

Comment: Mary is a variable, due to starting with a capital letter. Use mary instead.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264828/prolog-working-with-capital-letter

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
person( john , red      , footballer ).
person( mary , brunette , actor      ).

friend( john, mary ).
```

etc.

Then its as easy as something like this:

```
all_johns_friends_are_footballers :-
  ( friend(john, A ) ; friend( A , john ) ), % Find each friend of john
  \+ person( A , _ , footballer ) ,          % Are they not a footballer?
  !,                                         % if so, eliminate the choice point
  fail.                                      %   and fail hard.
all_johns_friends_are_footballers .          % otherwise, succeed. John either has no friend or they are all footballers.
```